# UITableView rowHeight animation takes too long

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

I'm having a problem animating a change in `rowHeight` for my tableview. The animation is taking a long time (about 3 seconds) on an iPad 3 (first gen retina).  However, it only takes this long if I'm *expanding* the `rowHeight` when the tableview is near the middle-to-bottom of the list or *decreasing* the `rowHeight` in the middle of the list.  When it's at the top, the animation works fine. Things to note:

1. I am subclassing `UITableView` and overriding the `setEditing:animated` method, which is where I change the rowHeight.
2. I'm trying not to use `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` as my table can have as many rows as the user wants. Some users may even have hundreds of thousands of rows if they imported data.
3. When the user puts the table in "editing" mode, I want the row heights to grow by a certain amount (currently by `30.0f`), where I display a range of options for each cell (thinks like "delete", "copy", "print", "share", etc).
4. Because the row heights are changing, I grab the path of the top-most displayed cell before the rowHeight change and then scroll the tableview to the appropriate path after the rowHeight change so the user doesn't loose their place. If I do not scroll at all, the delay is minimally better (perhaps 2.5 seconds instead of 3) and the list ends up in a completely different place than it started out in.
5. If I do not animated the changes (aka: `beginUpdates` & `endUpdates`) and instead simply call `reloadData`, the change is instant.  Of course, there's no animation then.
6. I have tried using `[self reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:self.indexPathsForVisibleRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]` to no effect (it takes forever).
7. I have tried placing `beginUpdates` & `endUpdates` in just about every conceivable placement within the code, all to no effect.
8. I've tried computing and directly setting `contentOffset`, but ended up with some weird effects, like tableCells not being refreshed, etc.
9. I did some time profiles and discovered most of the time was spent in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. So I logged the number of times `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called during the animation:

   1. Without `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atPosition:animated` : **59 times**.
   2. With `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atPosition:animated` : **67 times**.
   3. Using `reloadData` instead of `beginUpdates` & `endUpdates` : **8 times**.

Here's the code, which is pretty simple, really:

```
- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(1, _sectionView.superview ? _sectionView.bounds.size.height + 1 + self.bounds.origin.y : 1 + self.bounds.origin.y);
    NSIndexPath *path = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    CGFloat rowHeight = self.viewType.viewHeight.floatValue + (self.editing ? FlxRecordTableCellEditingHeight : 0);
    self.rowHeight = rowHeight;
    [self beginUpdates];
    [self endUpdates];
//    [self reloadData];
    [self scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
//    [self reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:self.indexPathsForVisibleRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

It appears that when `rowHeight` is changed, `UITableView` calculates what new rows should be at the current `contentOffset` and then attempt to animate to those new rows (including all rows in between), even though I'm telling it to move to the same cells it started out with. I suspect that if I were to increase the change in rowHeight (say, from `30.0f` to `45.0f`), the problem would grow worse as `UITableView` would have to animate through even more rows for the change.  What I want I need is for `UITableView` to first move to the new cells and then animate the change for only those cells.  However, I cannot seem to find a way to do this.

**UPDATE**

Holy {favorite_euphamism}! ...  I've been trying to make `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` more efficient to no avail.  So I ran a separate count of how many times `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` ends up *creating* new cells (rather than reuse them).  During the animation, `UITableView` isn't just requesting cells 59 - 67 times, *it's creating **59-67** new cells* by returning `nil` for `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.  No wonder it's taking so long.... and it's spiking my memory as well (thank you Xcode 5 for displaying that...). While I've done as much as I can to make my cells efficient, they're still complex views and definitely *not* designed for that much creation.  There's gotta be a way around this...

Any help or idea would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the problem description. I've been fumbling around with UITableView and its minions for the last three weeks, trying to get some editing/highlighting/animation/height expansion right, so I can feel your pain.

Comment: I believe it may be possible to fix this by implementing `tableView:rowHeightForIndexPath`, returning the new height, reload only the visible rows and scroll to the first cell in the old position. After the animation, reload the table (it's state will be inconsistent) and scroll to the new path position (without animation). The user will see a "flicker" after the animation (from the reload) but that's all, and you could get rid of it by using an overlay. Of course, I don't want to use `rowHeightForIndexPath`, but this might work in iOS 7 with it's new tableview methods for estimating height.

Comment: Row height animation worked for me when using `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`. In iOS 7.0 the beginEditing/endEditing dance reloaded all heights immediately (no matter on scroll position). In 7.1 it reloads only the visible row heights and uses estimated heights to determine position. I'm now down to having my own row height cache in the controller which I invalidate when I see fit.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe At the moment, I'm supporting iOS 5.1+. So `heightForRowAtIndexPath` will get called for each row in the table when `UITableView` first loads. If the user has 100,000 records, that method gets called 100,000 times. Apple recommends avoiding that method if your table will have more than 1,000 rows. My understanding is in iOS 7 they use the `estimatedHeight` property on `UITableView` to avoid all those calls (defers the exact calculations to scroll time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution I came up with is a hack at best, but it is working for the time being.  It's possible that Apple has fixed this problem with the upcoming iOS 7.1 update according to [Nikolai Ruhe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104790/nikolai-ruhe), but I haven't messed with the beta yet so I can't confirm it.

Unfortunately, I was forced to implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.  I didn't want to, but luckily most people have updated to iOS 7 and I can conditionally use the `estimatedRowHeight` property (iOS 7 only) on `UITableView` to mitigate the performance issues of large tables for iOS 7... every one else kind of gets screwed. I'm close to making my app "iOS 7 Only" so it won't be an issue for long (or for very many users).

I added 3 new iVars to my class: `CGFloat _rowHeight`, `CGFloat _imminentRowHeight`, and `NSIndexPath *_anchorPath`.  The `_rowHeight` variable is returned by default. However, if `_anchorPath` has been set, `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` will conditionally return `_imminentRowHeight` if `indexPath.row >= _anchorPath.row`.  This keeps the `contentOffset` for the `_anchorPath` the same during the transition so that `UITableView` doesn't try to animated through several dozen tableview cells, which was the original problem:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (_anchorPath){
        return indexPath.row >= _anchorPath.row ? _imminentRowHeight : _rowHeight;
    }
    return _rowHeight;
}
```

I created a new method to separate out my logic, `updateRowHeight`.  I'd like to again point out this this is a subclass of `UITableView`, so replace `self` with your `_tableView` iVar if you're doing this from a view controller:

```
- (void) updateRowHeight{
    CGFloat cellHeight = self.viewType.viewHeight.floatValue;
    CGPoint anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, _sectionView.superview ? _sectionView.bounds.size.height + 1 + self.bounds.origin.y : 1 + self.bounds.origin.y);
    _anchorPath = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:anchorPoint];
    _imminentRowHeight = cellHeight + (self.editing ? FlxRecordTableCellEditingHeight : 0);
    if (!_anchorPath){
        _rowHeight = _imminentRowHeight;
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(estimatedRowHeight)]){
            self.estimatedRowHeight = _rowHeight;
        }
        return;
    }
    if (_imminentRowHeight == _rowHeight) return;

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        _rowHeight = _imminentRowHeight;
        NSIndexPath *anchor = _anchorPath;
        _anchorPath = nil;
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(estimatedRowHeight)]){
            self.estimatedRowHeight = _rowHeight;
        }
        [self reloadData];
        [self scrollToRowAtIndexPath:anchor atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
    }];
    [self beginUpdates];
    [self endUpdates];
    //We must scroll the anchor Path into the top position so that when we reload the table data positions don't change
    [self scrollToRowAtIndexPath:_anchorPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Some things to note:

1. I escape out of the method early if no update is needed. This occurs if the row height isn't changing or if no anchorPath was found, which happens if there are no rows displayed or the table hasn't loaded yet.  `UITableView` has to do a lot of work here, so it's best to not do the work unless necessary.
2. I use `CATransaction` to set the animation context so that I can attach a completion block to it. `begin/endUpdates` will use the current animation context if one is available, else it will create its own... very convenient that.
3. I scroll (animated) the anchor path to the top position so that the table view won't "jump" when I reload the table data.  Again, after reloading the data I scroll again (without animation) so that the table appears to be exactly the same as before the reload.
4. I have to reload the table because I've only change the row heights for cells "below" the anchor path. Until I reload, `UITableView` thinks everything "above" the anchor path has the previous (and incorrect) row height.  This is why I set `_rowHeight = _imminentRowHeight;` and `_anchorPath = nil;` before I reload the table. I must then scroll to the anchor path (not animated) after the reload because the offset of the anchor path has changed now that all previous rows have the new row height.
5. There is a very slight "flicker" when the table reloads. For my app at least, only the cell text "flickers" and that's because I'm using custom drawing routines that asynchronously draw the text. So it's possible there won't be any flicker at all for others.  For me, the effect is so slight that I'm probably going to ignore it.  I'm toying with the idea of displaying an overlay but since we're talking about a whole screen-worth of content, I doubt it'll work well.